# strlen of char array & putchar

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, c-strings, strlen, putchar

I am compiling and running this code:

```
// hello, world!, without printf

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char a[7] = "hello, ";
char b[7] = "world!\n";

void putCharArray(char *ray) {
  for (int i = 0 ; i < strlen(ray) ; i++ ) 
    { putchar(ray[i]);  }    
}

void main() {
    putCharArray(a);
}
```

on Ubuntu 20 using gcc. When it runs it outputs:

```
hello, world!
```

So it seem like it runs past the 'a' array and right
into the 'b' array.

Would someone please explain how that is? Please and
thank you.

Comment: *Undefined behavior*. Your array `a` is too small to hold the null-terminator, so calling `strlen` on it invokes UB

Comment: For the fun of it, put something in between the line of a and b say int i = 34;.

Comment: FWIW your loop is doing double work traversing the string (or even quadratic - if the code is poorly optimized). Instead of using `strlen` you should print as long as you don't encounter the terminator `\0` (because this is what `strlen` does). And this way you will also see your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

The both character arrays

```
char a[7] = "hello, ";
char b[7] = "world!\n";
```

do not contain strings because the sizes of the arrays are not enough large to include as an initializer the terminating zero character `'\0'`. So calling the function `strlen` invokes undefined behavior.

You should declare the arrays like

```
char a[] = "hello, ";
char b[] = "world!\n";
```

or like (specifying the sizes of the arrays at least not less than 8)

```
char a[8] = "hello, ";
char b[8] = "world!\n";
```

Or you could change the function the following way

```
void putCharArray( const char *ray, size_t n ) {
  for (size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
    { putchar(ray[i]);  }    
}
```

and call it like

```
putCharArray( a, sizeof( a ) );
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: Thank you very much!